# WebMatrix 3 deploying to IIS on the the local machine

Tags: deployment, webmatrix

I'm trying to deploy a WebMatrix 3 application to my local IIS. What values do I enter for the settings? I do not have a host server as I'm trying to put this on the local IIS on my laptop, what do I enter for server. What values do I use for the site name and Destination URL? I have published in Visual C#, no problem. All I had to do was choose the Publish option. Everything was set up. Not the case with WebMatrix.

Comment: Do you have a run -> button in the webmatrix IDE?

Comment: I know this is old, but did you get this right? [@Irb](http://stackoverflow.com/users/611545/lrb) If I can run it does it mean I can also deploy it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy to your local machine, it needs to be set up as a Web Deploy server:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

After you set that up, you can use the publish dialog to publish to localhost.